# Python assert a function is called within a certain `with` statement's context

Tags: python, mlflow

In python I would like to check that a given function is called within a `with` statement of a given type

```
class Bar:
 def __init__(self, x):
  self.x = x
 def __enter__(self):
  return self
 def __exit__(self, *a, **k):
  pass

def foo(x):
 # assert that the enclosing context is an instance of bar
 # assert isinstance('enclosed context', Bar)
 print(x*2)

with Bar(1) as bar:
 foo(bar.x)
```

I could do something like enforcing an arg passed into `foo` and wrapping functions in a decorator i.e.

```
class Bar:
 def __init__(self, x):
  self.x = x
 def __enter__(self):
  return self
 def __exit__(self, *a, **k):
  pass

def assert_bar(func):
 def inner(bar, *a, **k):
  assert isinstance(bar, Bar)
  return func(*a, **k)
 return inner


@assert_bar
def foo(x):
 print(x*2)

with Bar(1) as bar:
 foo(bar, bar.x)
```

but then I would have to pass around `bar` everywhere.

As a result I'm trying to see if there's a way to access the `with` context

Note: The real world application of this is ensuring that [`mlflow.pyfunc.log_model`](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyfunc.html#mlflow.pyfunc.log_model) is called within an [`mlflow.ActiveRun`](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.ActiveRun) context, or it leaves an `ActiveRun` open, causing problems later on

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for `mlflow.active_run()`, the function documented directly below `mlflow.ActiveRun`, but I'm not familiar enough with mlflow to be sure.

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: Please don't ever use single-space indentation with Python. [Four spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is standard, and practical. Since indentation is significant with Python single space indentation is _insane_. It is far too easy to misread. If you absolutely _must_ violate PEP 8, please use at least two spaces.

Comment: You are right, `mlflow.active_run()` solve my issue and lets me check for a valid `mlflow.ActiveRun`. I'm still interested to know if there is a way to actually get the enclosing context

Comment: If you want to ensure `foo` is called in such context, perhaps it should take the context manager (or a value returned by the context manager's `__enter__` method) as an argument. In general, the context itself is not a first-class object; it's purely a matter of syntax.

Comment: A special case is that `foo` itself is *not* a regular function, but a method provided by the instance of `Bar` (or by the object returned by `Bar.__enter__`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an ugly way to do it: global state.

```py
class Bar:
    active = 0
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __enter__(self):
        Bar.active += 1
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *a, **k):
        Bar.active -= 1

from functools import wraps

def assert_bar(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*vargs, **kwargs):
        if Bar.active <= 0:
            # raises even if asserts are disabled
            raise AssertionError()
        return func(*vargs, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Unfortunately I don't think there is any non-ugly way to do it. If you aren't going to pass around a `Bar` instance yourself then you must rely on some state existing somewhere else to tell you that a `Bar` instance exists and is currently being used as a context manager.

The only way you can avoid that global state is to store the state in the instance, which means the decorator needs to be an instance method and the instance needs to exist before the function is declared:

```py
from functools import wraps

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.active = 0
    def __enter__(self):
        self.active += 1
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *a, **k):
        self.active -= 1
    def assert_this(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*vargs, **kwargs):
            if self.active <= 0:
                raise AssertionError()
            return func(*vargs, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

bar = Bar(1)

@bar.assert_this
def foo(x):
    print(x + 1)

with bar:
    foo(1)
```

This is still "global state" in the sense that the function `foo` now holds a reference to the `Bar` instance that holds the state. But it may be more palatable if `foo` is only ever going to be a local function.

Comment: Looks like the best solution for the general case. @user2357112-supports-monica 's solution works for the `mlflow.ActiveRun` case and it is essentially doing a similar thing, storing a global state of runs active, with `ActiveRun == Bar` in the general case. @chepner also pointed out that you can't get the generic context a function is called within.